# Roles.IsUserInRole is not working while trying to make an ASP.NET TableRow Invisible

Tags: c#, asp.net, syntax, tags, roles

I am trying to hide a ASP.NET Table row, but below code part is not working, I don't know what is wrong with the syntax.

**Not Working:**

```
<asp:TableRow runat="server" Visible='<%# Roles.IsUserInRole("ARoleThatIsNotInDatabase") %>'>
</asp:TableRow>
```

**Working:**

```
<asp:TableRow runat="server" Visible='False'>
</asp:TableRow>
```

**Working:**

```
if (System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole("ARoleThatIsNotInDatabase"))
{//Not Entering this area as expected
}
```

Comment: Double check you are actually calling `this.DataBind();` in your page

Comment: Seems exceedingly unlikely to be related to `Roles.IsUserInRole`. What do you see with `Visible='<%# true %>'` and `Visible='<%# false %>'`?

Comment: @Jupaol, I added this.databind(); to page load and is started working, please write it as answer and I will be accepting it, but actually I couldn't not understand the logic behind by reading the definition of databind method, I would be appreciated if you include any document related to the logic.

Comment: OK I already posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested:

Double check you are actually calling

```
this.DataBind();
```

On your page